Issue using XCUITest Scanning Websites with Safari iOS
I'm having this issue when I scan my application on iOS to automate it. Appium is getting wrong coordinates of the objects and that causes mismatch clicks or zero-identification. Specifically, I use Appium for Tricentis Tosca and the objects that I get are completely defaced and generate an error on my test.
Here is an example of how I receive all websites
Example: The image coordinates are defaced in comparation with real ones
Another example with Tosca at time of clicking that object or something
Error generated by this issue in Tricentis Tosca
I tried using so many different capabilities to calibrate all the positions and drivers like Safari
